# Vector of thread objects: Removing after completion

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, mutex

I have a vector of thread objects and every time a client connects to my server, a new thread object is added to the vector, and the thread runs my clientHandler function.

```
std::vector<std::thread> clientThreads; //vector of client threads
.../*setting up server.*/
std::mutex clientThreadsM;

while(1) {
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> CTlock(clientThreadsM);

    if(clientThreads.size() <= MAX_THREADS){
        clientThreads.push_back(std::thread(clientHandler, newsockfd, std::ref(userandPass), std::ref(UserAccounts)));
    }
CTlock.unlock();
}
```

However, there are two important adjustments I need to make.

1. Rather than an if loop, I need to make it so the program waits for the condition that the condition: clientThreads.size() <= MAX_THREADS
   to be true so that every client eventually connects to the server. Is there an (efficient) facility for this in C++?
2. I would like to make it so when the threads finish, they are erased from the vector, such to make room for another client. Surely this must somehow be done as part of the clientHandler function because I can't have the while loop waiting for the threads to finish. Is there a way to somehow have the threads 'self-remove' from the vector when completed?

Comment: For #1 take a look at condition variables. For #2, if you are constantly removing elements from the vector, perhaps a vector is not an ideal data structure.

Comment: If the threads self-remove themselves from the vector, what is the point of having the vector at all? You basically only have a thread counter and for that you may as well use some `std::atomic<int> thread_counter;` and get rid of the vector.

Comment: You shouldn't use the term "if loop" because people get angry at you and because it's technically not correct.

Comment: I was using the vector of thread objects rather than explicitly declaring different threads to avoid having to declare a fixed number of threads at compile time. I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: You just don't put the threads in the vector. Instead of `clientThreads.push_back(std::thread(...));` you write `std::thread(...).detach();`. The [detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) is important here, otherwise the [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) will do bad things.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that you're suggesting instead of writing
        clientThreads.push_back(std::thread(clientHandler, newsockfd, 
    std::ref(userandPass), std::ref(UserAccounts)));
I should write
    std::thread(clientHandler, newsockfd, std::ref(userandPass), 
    std::ref(UserAccounts)).detach();
 and this will create a new thread object just like what I have been pushing to the vector, detaching it and negating the need for the vector altogether?

Comment: Basically yes. The thread object will immediately be destroyed, but the thread will keep running. The problem is that you now cannot wait for the threads to finish because you don't have the thread object to call [`.join()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) on and there may be other reasons you need the vector, but for the code shown and assuming self-removing is what you really wanted you don't need the vector.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you.

Comment: @TrancendentalObject Be careful with `.detach()` because a `detach`ed thread will be terminated if the program terminates before the thread exits. If you detach, you'd have to synchronise manually and make sure that all `detach`ed threads have finished processing their tasks before `main()` returns.

Comment: It's fine because main includes an infinite while loop that is meant to run indefinitely. It main ends before the thread exits, the server has crashed.